# Trouble making WP slideshow responsive

Tags: css, wordpress, responsive-design, slideshow

Although I just launched my website, there is only one publicly visible bug (that I know of) that I need to fix and I haven't managed on my own.

I'm running Wordpress 4.4.1 with the Corpo theme and toolkit, the latter which comes with a nice slideshow on the front page and portfolio project pages. Unfortunately, the author of the theme+plugin vanished from the earth: no longer active on the WP forums and her website/domain name is no longer renewed.

Long story short: the slider code is working responsively on the front page, but not on the project pages.

My website is located at http://www.jurjenbarel.com/

The project slider gets really ugly when you get under 540px width, because the container div is set at 540px. I can't set the container at `max-width: 540px;` because it will make the slideshow ridiculously small.

If someone with better knowledge of CSS has any idea on a fix, I would be very grateful!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: set `@media screen and (max-width: 959px) .entry-content img` to `max-width: 100%`

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you!